# Why does my wifi DNS remain the same after I change it in 17.10?

Tags: wireless, 17.10, dns

When I go to IPV4 settings for my wifi and change the DNS IP to Google and click apply, it doesn't change.

The DNS remains the old value in the details tab.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try reconnecting the network

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. My computer is connected to the wifi